# Formulários em Modal Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mvc, modal, jquery-validate, asp-net-core

Estou com um sistema que todos os formulários (Views) são em Modal Bootstrap.

A View Index carrega todas as PartialView. Abaixo a Index:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no botão Cadastrar, por exemplo, uma função JavaScript acessa a Action Create via AJAX, e esta por sua vez retorna a ParialView '_Create':

JavaScript:

[image: JS]

Action:

[image: C#]

A modal com o formulário de cadastro é carregada na tela:

[image: modal create]

Ao submeter o formulário, clicando em Gravar, é feita uma verificação interna se o nome já existe:

[image: Create post]

Em um formulário normal, estático, isso funcionaria beleza. Mas nesse caso a PartialView é retornada como uma página estática, e sem Layout:

[image: partial]

Alguém já se deparou com esse cenário e poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você está submetendo a página a partir de um form na página ou via jquery com ajax?

Comment: A partir de um form, botão submit. Pensei em criar um método ajax pra verificar a existencia primeiro, e de acordo com o retorno submeter o formulário. Mas é outra coisa que  eu não sei ainda como funciona. Submeter o formulário no JavasCript.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui. Tem que fazer tudo no JavaScript. Não sei se meu código oferece a melhor solução, mas ficou assim:

Primeiro, no controlador eu separei a função que verifica a existência da entidade, para que pudesse fazer a verificação antes de submeter o formulário:

[image: controller]

Então mudei o botão do tipo Submit que submetia o formulário ao Controller, o deixando como type button, chamando uma função JavaScript (CrateBanco), conforme a baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que há duas funções JavaScript. A primeira verifica a existência do objeto, e de acordo com o resultado aciona ou não a função 'SubmeterFormulário'. Essa função realiza o evento submit, enviando os dados para Action Create, que persiste os dados.

Answer (score 0):

Dessa forma eu mantenho a Modal Bootstrap aberta enquanto verifico a existencia dos dados digitados. E consigo fornecer a resposta ao usuário sobre essa condição, antes de persistir os dados.